# How to build a form builder object with FormBuilder.new in rails 3.1.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We need to create a form builder object with FormBuilder.new in controller. Here is what we are doing now:

```
@f = ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.new(:invoice, @invoice, self, {}, proc {} )
```

There is an error saying:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `fields_for' "invoiceController.."
```

We believe the @f is not a form builder object and that's why fields_for can not be recognized. The issue seems with the self parameter which is current view in definition. What is the right way to build a form builder object with FormBuilder? Thanks.

Comment: Solved the problem by putting the definition of @f in the same js.erb file. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're not going to get it to work with those parameters in the controller is that you call 'self' for the 'template' parameter, which is only actually the template ... from within the template. In the controller, self is the controller, not the template.